# Spinner doesn't get populated from string array

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to populate Spinner from string array. I have tried various approaches from different solutions on SO, but every time the spinner is empty.

Note: I am using the spinner in actionbarsherlock (as a navigation list)

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);
    IcsSpinner spinner = (IcsSpinner) menuItem.getActionView();

    // Approach 1 
    // using Spinner Adapter

    SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 10) {
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.news_menu, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    } else {
        mSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity,
                R.array.news_menu,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Spinner Count = " + mSpinnerAdapter.getCount());


    //Approach 2
    //using ArrayAdapter

    Resources res = getResources();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            res.getStringArray(R.array.news_menu));

    Log.d(Const.DEBUG, "Adapter Count = " + adapter.getCount());

    //Approach 3
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            activity, R.array.news_menu,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    //spinner.setSelection(0);
}
```

Both the mSpinnerAdapter and adapter(array) show the count as 4. Here is my news_menu string array

```
<string-array name="news_menu">
    <item>News</item>
    <item>Tour Dates</item>
    <item>Festival News And Rumors</item>
    <item>Late Night Performances</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: its populated just diffrence is you not shown because of spinner text color

Comment: @DigveshPatel, I thought so, but when i click on the spinner, it doesn't open, and also, the width of the spinner is almost zero, which leads me to believe that the spinner is not populated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm used to do something like that for populating spinner from ressource array :

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.news_menu, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Nope.. same result... spinner is empty

Comment: Ok sorry. Maybe it's a problem with your xml file, mine is stocked in res/values and has <ressources> as root element and it works fine.